# Apply dictionary to dataframe column containing strings

Tags: pandas, dictionary, normalization

I am trying to apply a dictionary to a dataframe column that contains rows of strings, eg:

0       [some, text, etc...

1       [other, text...

And have used the code below that works on a single string but not for a dataframe:

```
dict = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\dictionary.csv', header=None, dtype={0: str}).set_index(0).squeeze().to_dict()

def dictionary(text):
    for x in dict:
        for y in text:
            if dict[x][0] == y:
                        y == x[1]
            
                        text = ' '.join(dict.get(y, y) for y in text)
                        return
                
df['Processed'] = df['Processed'].apply(dictionary)
df['Processed']
```

producing the following error

```
<ipython-input-75-decedde15a18> in dictionary(text)
      5 def dictionary(text):
      6     for x in dict:
----> 7         for y in text:
      8             if dict[x][0] == y:
      9                         y == x[1]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Appreciate any help/guidance as to what I am doing wrong! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error can come out if you have NaN value in your Data Series